# Infinite limit proof

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Prove that

$\lim_{x→+∞} \ln ⁡x =+∞$

I know that $f(x) = \ln x$ can be written as

$\ln x$   if $x>1$

and

$0$ if $x=1$

Do these have any useful to prove the limit above?

Comment: What facts do you know that may be relevant? In particular: What definition of $\ln$ are you using? Have you covered exponential functions? Is there any specific text you are using?

Comment: I'm using a course pack for advance calculus 1, I haven't learnt any thing about Taylor theorem yet, so before that, I can use anything.

Comment: If you're looking at a limit as x→∞, then what happens when x=1 is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, given any $M>0$, when $x>e^M$, we have that $\ln x>M$. This shows that $lim_{x\to +\infty}\ln x=+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ M \in \mathbb{R}$ be given. Try to find the numbers whose image is greater than $M$.

HINT: if $f(x)=M$, then $x=e^M$, and $ln(x)$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limit proof.

Note: $ f(x) = ln(x) $ is continuous on the interval:
$$ I = (1,\infty) $$

By the definition of an infinite limit at $ \infty: $

If for any real number $ N \gt 0 $ there is some number
$ M \gt 0 $ such that
$ x > M $   implies    $ f(x) > N $

then
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \infty $$.

For any $ N \in \Bbb R $ , choose M so that:

$$  M \gt e^N  $$
Notice this makes $ M \gt e^0 = 1 $ for all $ N \gt 0$ so:
$$ M \gt 1 $$

The goal is to show that:
$$ x \gt M \implies f(x) \gt N $$
(expression 1)

where
$$ f(x) = ln (x) $$
First, the hypothesis of expression 1,
expression 1a,

$$ x \gt M $$
is examined.
Since
$$ f(x) = ln(x) $$

is increasing on the interval I, take natural logarithms to both sides of expression 1a:

$$ ln(x) \gt ln(M) $$
(equation 1)

The conclusion is now to use:
expression 1b:

$ ln(x) \gt N $

M has already been chosen to be:
$$ M \gt e^N $$
so that by (using equation 1):

$$ ln(x) \gt ln (M) \gt ln(e^N) = N $$
or,
$$ ln(x) \gt N  $$
Thus:
$$ f(x) \gt N $$
Hence: by the definition of a limit at infinity:  for any real $ N \gt 0 $  there is some number:
$ M \gt e^N $ which was chosen such that
$ x \gt M $  implies  $ f(x) \gt N $  which proves:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} ln(x) = \infty $$

Answer (score 0):

The function $\ln x$ is increasing. Therefore it suffices to indicate a sequence $x_n$ such that $\ln x_n$ tends to infinity. Take $x_n=3^n.$ Then $$\ln 3^n=n\ln 3> n$$